# Core Data calculation result at startup

Tags: cocoa, core-data, binding

Thanks for the help.

I have a doc based Core Data app consisting of a table with two columns. The column cells are populated with US Currency dollar values. I have two labels at the bottom of each column with Number formatters. Each label displays the sum of it's respective column. I'm doing this with bindings:

- Bound to the arrayController
- Controller Key - arrangedObjects
- modelKey - @sum.regAmount, @sum.regAmount1

The label attribute Types are int 16 in the data model.

Anyway, these calculations work fine, and the resulting values are displayed at startup.

What I need to do is also display the difference between the two resulting sums at startup in a third label. For some reason I can't pick up the sum values to preform the calculation.

This action works using a sender:

```
(runningBalance.intValue = (theDeposits.intValue - theAmounts.intValue));
```

How can I automatically display the calculated difference of the two sums at startup without manually executing the action?

Thanks again.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an action, you need a model key you can bind to just as you do with the sums. Then you bind that to the label's display(?) property and it should be called automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In this case what would the Controller Key be and how would I state the modelKey to preform a difference calculation?